# take randomly sample based on groups of another dataset with no match cases

Tags: r

I have two datasets like these ones:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:20,
             Sex = rep(x = c(0,1), each=10),
             age = c(25,56,29,42,33,33,33,25,25,25,26,57,30,43,34,34,34,26,26,26),
             ov = letters[1:20])

df1 <- data.frame(Sex = c(0,0,0,1,1),
              age = c(25,33,39,41,43))
```

I want to take 1 random row for every group of sex and age of df according every group of df1, but not all cases of age in df1 match in df, so I want to impute for every group in df1 that no match in df the value of var ov which is related with the same sex and the closest age, something like this:

```
df3 <- rbind(df[c(8,7),2:4],c(0,39,"d"),c(1,41,"n"),df[14,2:4])
```

Note that the donor for case in which sex = 0 and age = 39 is the df[4,] and note that the donor for case in which sex = 1 and age = 41 is the df[14,]

How can I do this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` you can try something like this:

1) Convert data to `data.table` and add keys:

```
df1
dt1 <- as.data.table(df1) # convert to data.table
dt1[, newSex := Sex] # this will serve as grouping column
dt1[, newage := age] # also this
setkey(dt1, Sex, age) # set data.tables keys
dt1
   Sex age newSex newage
1:   0  25      0     25
2:   0  33      0     33
3:   0  39      0     39
4:   1  41      1     41
5:   1  43      1     43

# we do similar with df:
dt <- as.data.table(df)
setkey(dt, Sex, age)
dt
    id Sex age ov
 1:  1   0  25  a
 2:  8   0  25  h
 3:  9   0  25  i
 4: 10   0  25  j
 5:  3   0  29  c
 6:  5   0  33  e
 7:  6   0  33  f
 8:  7   0  33  g
 9:  4   0  42  d
10:  2   0  56  b
11: 11   1  26  k
12: 18   1  26  r
13: 19   1  26  s
14: 20   1  26  t
15: 13   1  30  m
16: 15   1  34  o
17: 16   1  34  p
18: 17   1  34  q
19: 14   1  43  n
20: 12   1  57  l
```

2) Using rolling merge we get `dtnew` with new groups:

```
dtnew <- dt1[dt, roll = "nearest"]
dtnew
    Sex age newSex newage id ov
 1:   0  25      0     25  1  a
 2:   0  25      0     25  8  h
 3:   0  25      0     25  9  i
 4:   0  25      0     25 10  j
 5:   0  29      0     25  3  c
 6:   0  33      0     33  5  e
 7:   0  33      0     33  6  f
 8:   0  33      0     33  7  g
 9:   0  42      0     39  4  d
10:   0  56      0     39  2  b
11:   1  26      1     41 11  k
12:   1  26      1     41 18  r
13:   1  26      1     41 19  s
14:   1  26      1     41 20  t
15:   1  30      1     41 13  m
16:   1  34      1     41 15  o
17:   1  34      1     41 16  p
18:   1  34      1     41 17  q
19:   1  43      1     43 14  n
20:   1  57      1     43 12  l
```

3) Now we can sample. In your case we can simply reorder rows in random order, and then take firs row of each group:

```
dtnew <- dtnew[sample(.N)] #create random order
sampleDT <- unique(dtnew, by = c("newSex", "newage")) #take first unique by newSex and newage
sampleDT
   Sex age newSex newage id ov
1:   0  56      0     39  2  b
2:   0  29      0     25  3  c
3:   1  43      1     43 14  n
4:   1  34      1     41 16  p
5:   0  33      0     33  7  g
```